# select li value which automatically updates select option javascript

Tags: javascript, list, select

Struggling to find a JavaScript solution for when you click on an li element, this will automatically update/change the select option to the same value as the li element, I've found the solution to this through jQuery however I need to complete this using pure javascript. Here's my HTML code below for reference. Basically when you click on the li, it needs to automatically update on the select option.

```
<ul id="target-clicks" class="target-clicks">  
 <li data-sizeval="1" class="target active">S</li>  
 <li data-sizeval="2" class="target">M</li>  
 <li data-sizeval="3" class="target">L</li>  
 <li data-sizeval="4" class="target">XL</li>
</ul>

<select aria-label="Select" name="attribute" id="attribute">
  <option value="" disabled="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">S</option>
  <option value="2">M</option>
  <option value="3">L</option>
  <option value="4">XL</option>
 </select>
```

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: When you say "struggling to find a solution", what have you tried? Can you share your attempts at writing native JS? Hint: add a click event listener to the `<li>` element and then set the blue of the `<select>` element...

Comment: What have you tried to achieve it? Please share the JS you tried.

Comment: This was what I tried but only for jQuery, was hoping to find the solution in JavaScript instead         
       var selectSize = $('#attribute');
          $('.target').click(function() {
            selectSize.val($(this).attr('data-sizeval')).change();
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple listener on the list will catch all child clicks. Then obtain the value and set it on the select:

```js
function onListClick(e) {
  const nextValue = e.target.getAttribute('data-sizeval');
  
  document.getElementById('attribute').value = nextValue;
}

document.getElementById('target-clicks').addEventListener('click', onListClick);
```

```html
<ul id="target-clicks" class="target-clicks">  
 <li data-sizeval="1" class="target active">S</li>  
 <li data-sizeval="2" class="target">M</li>  
 <li data-sizeval="3" class="target">L</li>  
 <li data-sizeval="4" class="target">XL</li>
</ul>

<select aria-label="Select" name="attribute" id="attribute">
  <option value="" disabled="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">S</option>
  <option value="2">M</option>
  <option value="3">L</option>
  <option value="4">XL</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of a select tag using pure javascript like below

```
document.getElementById("attribute").selectedIndex = 1; //Updating from "1"
```

The index will be the value that you get from list onclick.

Comment: The `selectedIndex` property is a number, so your `"1"` will be converted anyway; the quotes are therefore not necessary.

Comment: @Pointy agreed, updated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will do that this way...

```js
const
  UL_list     = document.querySelector('ul#target-clicks')
  UL_list_li  = document.querySelectorAll('ul#target-clicks > li')
, select_list = document.querySelector('select#attribute')
  ;
UL_list.onclick = ({target : liElm}) =>
  {
  if (!liElm.matches('li')) return;
  UL_list_li.forEach( li => li.classList.toggle('active', li === liElm));
  select_list.value = liElm.dataset.sizeval;
  }
select_list.onchange = e =>
  {
  let liElm = UL_list.querySelector(`li[data-sizeval="${select_list.value}"]`)
  UL_list_li.forEach( li => li.classList.toggle('active', li === liElm));
  }
// on page load..;
select_list.onchange() // first synchro select <--> li
```

```css
#target-clicks > li:hover
  {
  background : yellow;
  cursor     : pointer;
  }
#target-clicks > li.active
  { 
  color      : red; 
  background : lightblue;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="target-clicks" class="target-clicks">  
  <li data-sizeval="1" class="target">S</li>  
  <li data-sizeval="2" class="target">M</li>  
  <li data-sizeval="3" class="target">L</li>  
  <li data-sizeval="4" class="target">XL</li>
</ul>
  
<select aria-label="Select" name="attribute" id="attribute">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value="1">S</option>
  <option value="2">M</option>
  <option value="3">L</option>
  <option value="4">XL</option>
</select>
```